# Persist variable Rails application Controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have something like this on my application controller.

```
def selected_position
  @position = params[:position] if params and params.has_key?(:position)
end
```

Even with that validation, the value get lost accross the controllers calls. I don't want to use session for this, so there's any solution to keep that value? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A solution is to store the position on client side. Maybe local storage is a good option. But be aware that the data can be changed or leaked.

Answer (score 0):

HTTP is stateless by design and so, Rails controllers. The only way to store that between controller calls (a.k.a. sessions) is to store data on client side - session, cookies (or local storage), or server side - **database**, memory, file, ect.

Comment: In that case, how can I make a parameter to persist accross multiple calls? Thanks for your answer!